# Why can't I activate venv after creating an environment?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am trying to use venv for my own existing project for the first time. I am not sure how to activate an environment. (This is Ubuntu)

```
$ ~/scripts/Alloy_Defender$ python3 -m venv /home/tech/scripts/Alloy_Defender

$ ~/scripts/Alloy_Defender$ venv/bin/activate
bash: venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory

$ ~/scripts/Alloy_Defender$ .venv/bin/activate
bash: .venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory

$ ~/scripts/Alloy_Defender$ ls
AA_start.py  auths  bin  database  functions  include  lib  lib64  
main.py  psutiltest.py  __pycache__  pyvenv.cfg  searchonetest.py  
settings  share  spamtest.py  test.py  webapi  wsgi.py

$ ~/scripts/Alloy_Defender$ /bin/activate
bash: /bin/activate: No such file or directory

$ ~/scripts/Alloy_Defender$ bin/activate
bash: bin/activate: Permission denied

$ ~/scripts/Alloy_Defender$ sudo bin/activate
[sudo] password for tech: 

sudo: bin/activate: command not found
$ ~/scripts/Alloy_Defender$
```

I used the python readthedocs.io page to find out how to do this. Maybe I am interpreting it wrong? https://python.readthedocs.io/fr/latest/library/venv.html
[image]

Comment: It looks like your venv ended up installed incorrectly. Instead of being put in a folder `venv` the contents were put into your directory `Alloy_Defender`. If you want to install a venv in your current directory, you can omit the path altogether. Then you can just run `. venv/bin/activate` from the same directory (`.` is the same as `source`)

Comment: Darn..... haha I guess I will have to deactivate and remove all those files manually. Then make a `venv` folder in the parent folder of `Alloy_Defender` then reactivate. I think you are right. I remember seeing `. venv/bin/activate` in an example but I didn't know that that ` . ` is the same as `source`. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It should be:**

```sh
source env_pth/bin/activate
```

### OR

```sh
. env_pth/bin/activate
```

Comment: I did `source bin/activate`  and that worked! I didn't know I actually had to put the work `source` into the command. I assumed that meant for something else that I couldn't find. Thank you for explaining and confirming that.

Comment: No issue. You can try both command to activate env